# How can i build a project that depends on another build result?

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, multi-project

I'm working on organizing many Android Studio projects, the build is making with gradle.
My current scheme is:

MainProject :

- Dependency1 -(library project)
- Dependency2 -(library project)
- Dependency3 -(library project)
- Dependency4 -(library project)

settings.gradle

```
include ':SDK:Dependency1'
include ':SDK:Dependency2'
include ':SDK:Dependency3'
include ':SDK:Dependency4'

include "MainProject"
project(":MainProject").setProjectDir(new File("./ProjectName"))
```

MainProject/build.gradle

```
debugCompile project(path: ':SDK:Dependency1', configuration: 'debug')
releaseCompile project(path: ':SDK:Dependency1', configuration: 'release')
debugCompile project(path: ':SDK:Dependency2', configuration: 'debug')
releaseCompile project(path: ':SDK:Dependency2', configuration: 'release')
debugCompile project(path: ':SDK:Dependency3', configuration: 'debug')
releaseCompile project(path: ':SDK:Dependency3', configuration: 'release')
debugCompile project(path: ':SDK:Dependency4', configuration: 'debug')
releaseCompile project(path: ':SDK:Dependency4', configuration: 'release')
```

I want to refer it as aar libraries so my MainProject/build.gradle is becoming.

```
   compile "com.dependency.sdk.Dependency1:$SDKVersion"
   compile "com.dependency.sdk:Dependency2:$SDKVersion"
   compile "com.dependency.sdk:Dependency3:$SDKVersion"
   compile "com.dependency.sdk:Dependency4:$SDKVersion"
```

The problem is: when I do this the build fail at Configuration phase because the MainProject can't resolve the dependencies because the dependencies libraries aren't built yet.

How I can solve this without modify settings.gradle file ?(I want to have only one settings.gradle file).

Comment: what's the exact error you're getting? there is a [evalutaionDependsOnChildren](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#evaluationDependsOnChildren()) method but i'm not sure if it will help

Comment: The MainProject depends on aars libraries, aar will result from build of Dependency$X project, so the dependencies project are needing to be built before MainProject,  it is possible with only one settings.gradle file, how it could be done?.

Comment: The dependency should be `compile rootProject.project(':SDK:Dependency1')` let me know if that fixes it and I'll explain it in an answer

Comment: This was the initial solution, but now I need to reference as aar library `compile "com.dependency.sdk.Dependency1:$SDKVersion"` ,this dependencies will be deliverable libraries, let say third party libraries.